# Поиск и изменение одним запросом SQL

Tags: sql, update

Ребята почему так нельзя? (+=)

```
UPDATE table SET column += value WHERE id = 1;
```

Как написать по другому?

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table SET column = column + value WHERE id = 1;
```

Ну так сложилось...

Comment: А точно... протупил)